# Substitute row in Numpy if a condition is met

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, syntax

I have a matrix in NumPy as:

```
[[10, 10],
 [11, 10],
 [12, 10],
 [13, 10],
 [14, 10]]
```

My goal is to replace a row if a particular condition on the left element is met.

For example:

I have values: `z= 13, x=1, y=0`. I'd like something like:

> If one of the left elements is equal to z then replace the row with [x y]

So far I wrote something like this:

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([[10, 10],
     [11, 10],
     [12, 10],
     [13, 10],
     [14, 10]])
z = 13
x = 1
y = 0
values = np.where(values == [z, ], np.array([x, y]), values)
```

The code works well for replacing the left element (x is updated), but y for some reason stays the same or gets the value of another row somehow.

Does anyone know what I should do, or if there is another method?

Comment: what is `min_values`? I assume you mean `values`?

Comment: @JoshuaF edited, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `values[values[:, 0] == z] = [x, y]` -- i.e., rows whose 1st entry is `z` are set to `[x, y]`.

```
import numpy as np

values = np.array([[10, 10],
     [11, 10],
     [12, 10],
     [13, 10],
     [14, 10]])
z = 13
x = 1
y = 0

values[values[:, 0] == z] = [x, y]

print(values)
```

Comment: That returned `[[10 10]
 [11 10]
 [12 10]
 [0 0]
 [ 14  10]]`

Comment: Edited to include complete code, which outputs `[[10 10]
 [11 10]
 [12 10]
 [ 1  0]
 [14 10]]`

Comment: Thank you that seems to work! It was converting my values to `[0,0]` due to float-int conversion. Works now

Comment: glad to hear it!